# How can create multiple IP in squid.conf?

Tags: amazon-ec2, squid, elastic-ip

How can make multiple outgoing ip address on squid proxy single server?

I have configured multiple IP as below in squid.conf file, but when I try to send request using by Proxy, it’s sending from primary IP of the server. I want to send request by virtual IP.

```
 http_port 182.xx.xx.5:3131
 http_port 182.xx.xx.6:3132

 acl proxy1 src 182.xx.xx.5
 acl proxy2 src 182.xx.xx.6
    
 http_access allow proxy1
 http_access allow proxy2        
   
 tcp_outgoing_address 182.xx.xx.5 proxy1
 tcp_outgoing_address 182.xx.xx.5 proxy2
```

Please suggest me where I am wrong?

I have taken 2 Elastic IP’s in  AWS EC2 and configured that to point to the instance, where i installed squid proxy. Now I need to install multiple proxy servers on same instance with different out going IPs.